# k3s, traefik: static ip for ingress

Tags: traefik, k3s

I am at a lost, and there is probably something that I don't understand as kubernetes is still new to me.

I am running k3s, with metal-lb and traefik.
I have some websites that I am hosting internally trough traefik, and now I have a site that I want to host externally.

lets say I host site [www.internalsite.com](http://www.internalsite.com) internally
and I now want to host [www.externalsite.com](http://www.externalsite.com) externally,
both of the ingress is IP 10.2.2.50

```
kubectl -n internal get ing
NAME               CLASS     HOSTS                     ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
internalsite       traefik   www.internalsite.com      10.2.2.50   80, 443   10d

kubectl -n external get ing
NAME               CLASS     HOSTS                     ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
externalsite       traefik   www.externalsite.com      10.2.2.50   80, 443   15m
```

in this case I would need to port forward to 10.2.2.50,
but in this case, I can then spoof the fqdn of the internalsite for that IP and reach internalsite externally.

I am not sure of the correct approach for this, I was thinking that I just need to have seperate IP's for the ingress, so with metal-lb I create 2 address pools.

```
kubectl -n metallb-system get ipaddresspool
NAME          AUTO ASSIGN   AVOID BUGGY IPS   ADDRESSES
extservices   true          false             ["10.2.2.55-10.2.2.55"]
intservices   true          false             ["10.2.2.50-10.2.2.50"]
```

and then for the externalsite

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: externalsite
    namespace: externalsite
    labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: externalsite
    annotations:
        metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: extservices
spec:
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - www.externalsite.com
      # secretName: wildcard-cert-secret
      secretName: wildcard-externalsite-com-tls
    rules:
        - host: "www.externalsite.com"
          http:
              paths:
                  - path: "/"
                    pathType: Prefix
                    backend:
                        service:
                            name: externalsite
                            port:
                                number: 80
```

but as you can see in the ingress, it doesn't give me the right IP

can anyone shed some lights?